# how to replicate href="...#something" with jquery

Tags: jquery

It's hard to describe the whole problem but to make a long story short, I can't use href="...#something" but I need this functionality. Is there a way to replicate it with jquery? So I want to have something like this onclick="$('div#something').jumpThere();" but I don't know the exact name of the function. Could you please let me know whether jquery has such function and if yes, how it is called.

Comment: Care to explain why you can't use anchors?

Comment: Well, it's a really long story. I have a PHP script that parses and then does certain modifications to all the HTML content just before it gets sent to browser. And I've discovered a bug that messes up these anchors. I have only one place in the project where anchors are being used and my deadlines are really bad. So I need to find some quick workaround to have the project done. And a little later when I have time on my hands, I'll go into that PHP script and will fix the bug (which will take some time because that thing is complex).

Comment: How are they messed up? Why would you think JS could use these "broken" anchors, when simple links couldn't.

Comment: No, I am not about to use those broken anchors. They are really broken and can be fixed only after I fix that bug. What I am about to do is go to PHP and generate onclick="$('div#something').jumpThere();" for each link where I need to jump to anchor. That won't get broken because that PHP script won't touch onlick='' stuff.

Comment: hey Eugene, +1, I like your avatar... it's stupid fox.. :D

Comment: Haha yeah, it's good to see another fan of stupid fox here ))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need jQuery

```
window.location.hash = '#something';
```

should do it.

Comment: What is this... "JavaScript without using jQuery" you talk about? Some kind of black magic?

Comment: @Matti: It's Voodoo, if you're after specifics

Comment: Lol, thanks, it's exactly what I need! With all this fancy jquery stuff I forgot good old JS times :))

Comment: @Eugene: That virtually doesn't do anything different than a normal `href="#something"`. IMHO you should expand on how your anchors are broken, because I think you are fixing the wrong problem.

Comment: I think he meant that he can't (why? don't know) do this with simple `<a href='#something'>click</a>` tags.

Comment: Yeah true, the stuff inside href simply gets broken. So right now (thanks to the solution offered by Pointy) my code is href="#broken_anchor" onclick="window.location.hash = '#good_anchor';". I do know that this is an extremely dirty fix but I just need a temporarily workaround to save the day :)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult.  But i would look into on click, getting the .position() of the element you want to go to.  Then setting the window.scrollTop to that value (this will only work in some situations).  That would be where I would start: .position() and window.scrollTop